# How can I replace my code in servlet filter with spring Interceptor?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlet-filters, interceptor

I am new to the development of Web applications. For pre-processing of every request, I am using a servlet filter in which i get the requested uri and redirect it to a new uri if needed. Can i do the same with an interceptor class? 
Also , what is the best way to redirect a user to the login screen if he is not logged in?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i do the same with an interceptor class

: Yes you can do the same, here is a simple tutorial to get you started with interceptors: https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-interceptor.html

> what is the best way to redirect a user to the login screen if he is
>   not logged in?

If you are already using Spring then use Spring security it comes with a lot of features.

Comment: i dont know to use spring-security. Could you please give me a brief idea or suggest me a link on how to implement spring security in a spring mvc web app?

Comment: It's really easy here is a get started tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/